# Compiled function not showing in portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm working on an app that runs fine as a csx, but when I port it over to a compiled library per https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/ I face some issues.
Mainly the function doesn't show up in the UI.
I realise that there's currently a bug, however I added an empty csx file to the function folder, but that doesn't seem to help.
My code is here, in case anyone can spot something obvious: https://github.com/davidobrien1985/o365_functions (`master` is compiled library, `dev` is csx)

Cheers
David

Comment: Hey David, I did see the Twitter conversation with Donna. I'll take a look at this. Are you able to invoke the function? I just want to confirm the runtime is loading it as expected.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante yes, I am. At least I get back a 401 Unauthorized (guessing the URL is https://{functionApp}.azurewebsites.net/api/{functionName} ) , because I do not know the function key (as it's not showing up in the portal).

Comment: Strange... in the meantime, you can get your function keys by invoking Kudu APIs:
https://{functionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/masterkey for the master and https://{functionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/{name}/listsecrets for a function

Comment: Cool, David Ebbo actually already responded here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939994/how-to-get-function-url-without-portal) with a very helpful PowerShell helper script to get the keys and I was able to call the function.
However, no logs generated on KUDU (none in the portal obviously) and my Slackbot doesn't work. Because no logs, no way to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Portal issue that was causing this, and has now been addressed. The function should now show up and be running from the portal in this scenario.

Comment: And what do you know?! It now does, including logs and function URI.
Awesome work guys! 
Now get the VS tooling out for compiled functions (I know, around May) and it's really awesome ;)

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark this (and the other one) as Answered.

Comment: Nope!!! With no .csx file and a manual trigger, it does not show up in the new portal.... not even after restart!!!