# How to get function URL without portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

from my previous question on "function doesn't show in portal" ([Compiled function not showing in portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923789/compiled-function-not-showing-in-portal)) I am now facing the issue that because of that I am unable to use the portal to get the "Function URL" and the function key to auth with.
Is there a way to get the function key without access to the portal?

I know that via KUDU I can read the JSON file with the keys, but these are encrypted and I couldn't work out how to decrypt them.

Cheers
David

Comment: Please avoid referring to a previous question without linking to it.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following ARM API to get the URL and the secret:

```
post /subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionapp}/functions/MyFunction/listsecrets?api-version=2015-08-01
```

See also PowerShell equivalent [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/a0e948e217b7c318e28390bc81ca1c211e6c7991/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L388-L393).

Comment: Great, thanks. That worked.
This is decrypting the values in the json files that I can view via the KUDU portal, right?