# How get Azure Function URL directly by code in Azure Function Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure Portal, you can get function URL directly from portal. there is also another way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939994/how-to-get-function-url-without-portal) that you can get Azure Function URL using Azure ARM API. But I want to know, Is there any way to get "Function URL" by code (Node.js, Python, ...) in Azure Function Apps directly?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Node.js azure function, you can just use this line of code: `req.originalUrl`.

Detailed steps as below:

1.In Azure portal, create a Http Trigger function, select JavaScript as it's Programming Language.

2.In the index.js file, add this line of code: `context.log(req.originalUrl)`;

3.Sample code like below:

```
  module.exports = function (context, req) {

       context.log(req.originalUrl);
       //write you other logic below
  };
```

Please refer to the screenshot below for test result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working :). if there is any reference, I will be so much happier to know where it is.

Comment: @RezaAmya, you can refer to this [nodejs tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_request_object.htm)

Comment: What if it's timer-triggered function?